# league/oauth2-server key exposed in exception message when passing as a string and providing an invalid pass phrase

Tags: laravel, security, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Im currently using Laravel 10, which handles OAuth2 by "Laravel/Passport". Unfortunately, there is a vulnerability exposed, therefore I need to update my dependencies.

**Vulnerability Details see: https://github.com/CarlsonBuma/Laravel-Quasar-Authsystem/security/dependabot/3**

**Current Message:**
"Found 1 security vulnerability advisory affecting 1 package"

```
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Package           | league/oauth2-server                                                             |
| CVE               | CVE-2023-37260                                                                   |
| Title             | league/oauth2-server key exposed in exception message when passing as a string a |
|                   | nd providing an invalid pass phrase                                              |
| URL               | https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wj7q-gjg8-3cpm                                |
| Affected versions | >=8.3.2,<8.5.3                                                                   |
| Reported at       | 2023-07-06T21:07:27+00:00                                                        |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Problem**
Im not able to update the dependencies accordingly...

**Setup**

composer.lock

```
"require": {
                "league/oauth2-server": "^8.2",     // Update to 8.5
            },
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^11.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
```

**I tried:**
"Composer update" (Delete composer.lock file) the version of "league/oauth2-server" keeps the same.

**Looking for**
I need to update this dependencies in Laravel 10. Why the current versions is staying the same?

Comment: try to use  "league/oauth2-server": "*",  . It will auto  install the dependency , which is compatible to version . May be this work

Comment: Unfortunately, when I update, the composer-lock file is thrown back to it's old version

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I needed to manually update my composer.json file form "^11.8" -> "^11.8.8", as my current Laravel/Passport version was "11.8.4"

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^11.8.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
```

In case of an error while "composer update" please make sure to enable "extension=sodium" in your php.ini file.